# Power BI DAX - How can I extract the following Information?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Say I have 2 tables

Table:-1 ( From Here I extract the value of Height = 500m)

| Tower ID | Bottom Dia | Top Dia | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | 500 |

Table:-2 ( Now keeping 500 from table I need the minimum of the SRF values in table 2 corresponding to all heights less than 500 as min ( 0.25, 0.1,0.3,0.2) = 0.1 so on and so forth , so eventually for one tower ID I will have a single min SRF value.

| Tower ID | Mass | height | SRF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Cell 2 | 650 | 0.3 |
| 123 | Cell 2 | 500 | 0.25 |
| 123 | Cell 2 | 450 | 0.1 |
| 123 | Cell 2 | 200 | 0.3 |
| 123 | Cell 2 | 50 | 0.2 |

How can I achieve this using DAX or otherwise ?

Sorry I am really new and not sure how to even get started on this

Comment: If you create a relationship between the two tables, then you can use something like this in Table1:
MINX(
     FILTER('Table2',[height]<500),
     [SRF])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a relationship between the two tables, then you can use something like this in Table1:

```
MINX(
     FILTER('Table2',[height]<500),
     [SRF])
```

MINX will use the relationship between table1 and table2 to return only the related records, and then filter, and finally return the lowest SRF value.

Comment: Thanks @pieter .. So say if had to collect all the SRF values below 500 in a separate table and not just the minimum .. how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: FILTER('Table2', [height]<500)

But what are you trying to accomplish with this? return a table? a value?

Comment: I am trying to return a table because I want to then create a scatter plot with levels on y axis and SRF on x axis....

Comment: How could I modify this below to return a table with values less than current height ?
`Min_Bottom_Sec_Extreme_SRF = `
`VAR CurrentHeight = Bottom_Section_Overview_SRF[Height]`
`VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( TowerResultExtremeYielding[Extreme_SRF]),
        KEEPFILTERS (TowerResultExtremeYielding[Level] <= CurrentHeight )
    ) `
`RETURN
   Result`

Comment: Vikram, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "less than current height" Current as of what? Can you show me the expected output given the data you provided (thanks for that!)?